# Using NLTK in Python 2.7 on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: python, visual-studio, python-2.7, visual-studio-2015, nltk

I'm trying to install NLTK in Python in Visual Studio 2015. Visual Studio detects correclty in the solution windows under "Python Enviorment" voice. But if I use 'import ntlk' function it generates an exception:

un(shallow)copyable object of type

Am I doing something wrong?

If I run python directly from command line, without using VS, it works fine.

Thanks in advance for the help!